# v-if contains advanced statement

Tags: vue.js, if-statement

I have images with contains alt different names, and I want to make a filter with these names, what I want to do is for example if the "**current_variant**" is red I want to show images that have '**#red**' and images that do not have '**#**' together '**#yellow**' in that case.

> 1.image [image_alt#red]
> 2.image [image_alt#yellow]
> 3.image [image_alt]
> 4.image [image_alt]

current_variant.alt = image_alt#red

with this line, I manage to call images with alt names but the problem is on the second statement removes the first because it includes '**#**'

```js
v-if="current_variant.alt == '{{ media.alt }}' !== current_variant.alt.indexOf('#') > -1"
```

Comment: The question isn't easy to follow. It's unclear what input you have and what output you expect. Regardless, I'd suggest to not pollute a template with code-golf logic and just move this code to a computed or method and write it as proper JS that can be easily read and debugged

Comment: I guess that you doesn't need to wrap `media.alt` in curly braces since you're inside an v-if statement. All the code inside v-if will be parsed as javascript/vue normally. See example for reference: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is not clear but let me guess...

You probably have a list of images let's say a gallery and you are trying to do something similar to this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-poincare-j7enl?file=/src/App.vue

It would be very helpful though if you added more info on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry guys about my description, you guys are amazing, #sma that exactly what I want but with one more option, I have other images that don't have #color and I want to keep them always on the view

Comment: I find the answer buy using both Vue and liquid together, thank you everyone~
v-if="current_variant.alt.includes('{{ media.alt | split: "#" | slice: 1, 1 }}')"